# how to delete oldest mysql table records, but leave 1000 newest

Tags: mysql, sql

What query deletes oldest mysql table records, but leave 1000 newest. does not matter how mush records are there - I need 1000 newest of them.

Comment: Post your table structure and explain what is newest according to that table.

Comment: Please show the layout of the table.  Basically, you need a column that specifies the insert order, typically an auto incremented id or timestamp column.

Comment: Delete from Table where ID not in (Select ID from Table order by date desc limit 1000) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
delete from your_table
where id not in
(
   select * from 
   (
      select id from your_table
      order by id desc
      limit 1000
   ) x
)
```

The inner `select` returns the most recent 1000 ids. The other `delete` deletes all records but the ones from the inner `select`.

Comment: why is `select * from( .. ) x` subquery required ?

Comment: In Mysql you can't delete from the same table you are selecting from. But you can overcome this with another subselect in the middle.